# WCF Service Instance PER Host in IIS

Tags: wcf

I am currently hosting a WCF service inside of an MVC application in IIS.

Routes:

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("api/SitemapService", new MyServiceHostFactory(), typeof(IMyService)));

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

Service Host Factory:

```
    public class MyServiceHostFactory : ServiceHostFactory
    {
        public override ServiceHostBase CreateServiceHost(string constructorString, Uri[] baseAddresses)
        {
            //I figured I could use the baseAddresses here to determine the tenant being requested, but baseAddresses is always the first binding in IIS.
        }
    }
```

In IIS, I have two bindings:

```
local.wcftest.com:80
localtenant.wcftest.com:80
```

I have a ServiceHostFactory implementation overriding the CreateHostService method.  Inside of this method, we receive the `baseAddresses`.  No matter what configuration I've tried in my `web.config`, I can not get a service instance that uses the correct base address. `baseAddresses` always contains 1 address, and it's for the first binding listed in IIS.  The baseAddress matters in this case because based on the tenant, I need to inject an IoC container with the correct registrations to the service.

Is this something I can achieve?  I feel like I've tried many things, but I am unsure what else to try at this point, and feel like this should be a simple thing to do.

I do have multipleSiteBindingsEnabled as true in the web.config.